# Typos in String literal isn't working in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea, dart

[image]

I am seeing typo only in variable but not in `String-literal`, is there any option I need to enable? This works fine in Java side.

Comment: Please also add a comment before downvoting, let me know what's so wrong in this question, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had been an [issue](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-plugins/pull/767) and it is fixed in the latest Dart plugin `192.8052`.

Comment: Mentioned issue fixed in dart plugin release 201.7223.97. Make sure that your IDE version matches plugin's compatibility range (201.7223—201.*).

Comment: @Spatz Can you please tell me where did you find that release number?

Comment: Probably the fix was in a few earlier versions, but I specified the one I checked on. [Here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart/versions) are all versions of the plugin.

Comment: @Spatz `192.8052` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question! But you can rename "typoinstring" to "typoInString" to fix it!
Orther way you can save it to project-level dictionary!

Comment: I want IDE to report a warning when I am making typos mistake in String literal. IDE only shows warning for typos in variable but not in the String literal. I don't want to save a typo in my project dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think android studio want us to use camel case (professional way to give  names). so as we know there can't be space in-between name of any variable or class we use camel case. -

**Ex-**   instead of using -> user input/ userinput   (space is not allowed)
we use -> useInput                (it improves readability)